# icons for web technologies

Tags: website-design, icon

Hi I'm working on my own portfolio, and so I'd like to have some icons for technologies that I work with. So does anyone know of free icon sets that include css, php, c#, html5 and other web technology icons?

Comment: Please see the FAQ. You can find these with a simple Google search. Try "icon sets computer free" or "computer sets icon free," depending on your preference in newspaper headlines. :)

Comment: http://www.iconfinder.com/ - but still.. (-1)

Comment: I have heard of google before, It's not like I didn't try to find some using google. I just spent about an hour not really finding any definite match, so I thought - there's got to be a lot of web devs that have portfolios that use icons like this, and maybe there'd be an icon pack for the technologies  that I used, but apparently not really. Thank you for your kind suggestions though.

Comment: @Alan- Google gives machine results, stack exchange gives trusted community results- It's patronizing to say 'use google' just because it's a searchable term- the user is obviously looking for quality results from experts on this site, and that's exactly what this site is for.

Comment: @Yarin You are right but there are some scope defined for this site please see : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[www.iconfinder.com](http://www.iconfinder.com) should work out for you.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned:

https://iconpharm.com - open source icons (bunch of),

https://iconmonstr.com - free without a link,

https://icons8.com - free for a link,

Answer (score 1):

There's this set here:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/12/23/free-icon-set-for-web-developers-coded/

Dosen't have all the languages that you are looking for but could maybe give you a head start.

Answer (score 1):

If this question had by title "how to represent web technologies in icons":

You could draw or pick (from any of the other websites in the answers) a plain button with a certain color, and write the language over it with a nice text effect (shadows, glows, your preference). HTML5 has an icon, and it's a sort of shield that says html and has a big number 5 (superman reference?). You could do something similar with css, php and c+. Perhaps you could use different colors for each language.

Some psd buttons you could use as inspiration/background:

Round: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/05/simplito-a-free-social-icon-set/

Square: http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/free-social-media-icon-set